# kworker using lots of CPU if HDMI screen plugged in during resume

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, intel-graphics

I kept noticing in `top` that `kworker` was taking up lots of CPU, thereby making the laptop run hot with the fan on. Searching this you get a mix of "oh that's just the kernel *working* it's supposed to work you know" and very specific cases that seem separate to mine explained here.

However I have now tracked it down: if I resume from suspend with an HDMI monitor plugged in, I immediately get the kworker process problem. If I remove the cable, resume, then plug it in again: no problem.

I can't see any obvious errors in `journalctl -k` output.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 with `6.0.0-1006-oem #6-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Oct 18 20:01:16 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) graphics, I believe using module `i915`. Gnome 42.5 on Wayland.